# Can Python's psycopg2 use a password protected client certificate and key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2, tls1.2

I'm trying to use psycopg2 to connect to a cockroach DB server where client auth is required.

The connection strings typically look like this:

```
import psycopg2
c = psycopg2.connect("host=myhost dbname=mydb sslmode=verify-full sslcert=/root/.postgresql/aa/postgresql.crt sslkey=/root/.postgresql/aa/postgresql.key")
```

However, my key file is encrypted. My question is: Can psycopg2 handle password encrypted key files? What happens if postgresql.key is password protected? Does connect() prompt for a password to unwrap the key? Can a password to the key file be provided in the connection string?